# Google Maps API v3 PHP Request Returns Error

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use a PHP script to get the Lat/Long of an address using the Google Maps API v3. I have looked at many examples of how to do this, but none of them are working for me. I always get an error in my response. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&key=MY_API_KEY&address=1600+Pennsylvania+Avenue+Northwest+Washington+DC+20500";
echo $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
?>
```

And here is the output from that script:

> { "results" : [], "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }

I have tried everything I can think of to get this working. I have tried generating a new API key with my server IP address to no avail. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use the [web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) or the [v3 API geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)?

From php you should use the web service.  The documented URL is not the one I see in your post (http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json), it is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm not sure how I got the url I was using, but changing it to the one you mentioned fixed my problem! Why isn't the API key necessary though? How does Google track/limit my usage?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try sending the request without the key parameter, you won't see any mention of it in the geocoding [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Does http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=1600+Pennsylvania+Avenue+Northwest+Washington+DC+20500 work?